# Save multiple times at almost the same time in workligth JSONStore

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I want to add to JSONStore by  using a for cycle

so i call the saveToJSON() function inside the for with a length more than 500, but it doesnt add, and in console it shows succes but when i look in the jsonstore theres nothing,and number of the cycle for times that  i called to add to jsonstore is in a red bubble in console.

```
function saveToJSON(object) {

var data ={

    title :     object.title, 
    subtitle:   object.subtitle,         

  };

var options = {}; //default
WL.JSONStore.get('MyDataCollection').add(data, options)
  .then(function () {
    //handle success
    console.log("add JSONStore success");

    })
  .fail(function (errorObject) {
    //handle failure
    console.log("add JSONStore failure");

});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an array with the data you want to add and then passing that to JSONStore's add API. Remember to make sure that `WL.JSONStore.init` has finished successfully before calling the add API.

Example pseudocode:

```
//This is the data you want to add, you probably get this from a network call
var someData = [{title: 'hello'}, {title: 'world'}];

//This is an array that you will pass to JSONStore's add API
var someArray = [];

//Populate the array with data you want to pass to JSONStore's add API
for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
    someArray.push(someData[i]);
}

//Add data inside someArray to the collection called: MyDataCollection
WL.JSONStore.get('MyDataCollection').add(someArray)
.then(function () {

    //Do a find all operation on the collection called: MyDataCollection
    return WL.JSONStore.get('MyDataCollection').findAll();
})
.then(function (res) {

    //Print all the data inside the collection called: MyDataCollection
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});

//You may want to add .fail(function(){...}) to handle errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not really recommended to perform parallel operations in JSONStore. JSONtore is designed to work asynchronously. You can run JSONStore operations serially by using a for loop. However, your example does not show a for loop. Have you tried to do a for loop using smaller iterations? Maybe 2 rather than 500.